# How to decoding UTF8 encoded value in C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8

Cookie value stored in UTF8 Encoded value `Wuce%C3%B1o`. Acutual value is `Wuceño`. How to convert the encoded value in decode to get `Wuceño` in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`WebUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    string s = WebUtility.UrlDecode("Wuce%C3%B1o");
```

or [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    string s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Wuce%C3%B1o");
```